# How to recover when zooming makes Final Cut Pro unresponsive?

Tags: final-cut-pro-x

Every so often while I'm editing in Final Cut Pro, I zoom in or out with the trackpad and suddenly the app becomes unresponsive in a strange way - you can't click on anything, right-clicking the icon shows the normal menu with "Quit" at the bottom but it doesn't work. There's no spinner or anything - it feels like it's spawned a modal dialog window somewhere unreachable, so it's not a crash per se - more like it's gone into a weird undefined state. I've tried tabbing and "show all windows" and all sorts but no dice.

All I can do is force quit the app but it really feels like there might be a better way to fix this problem without doing so.

Has anybody else experienced this problem? I haven't had any luck on Google.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as it's not production related. You should file a bug report with Apple if this is a recurring bug in your software.

Comment: Voting to reopen. Anybody that uses Final Cut Pro should know that forcequitting and reopening FCP is just as part of your production workflow as color grading. One trick I found was turning off and turning back on your mouse. On the MX 3S you can tap underneath to disconnect bluetooth, same thing. This works 20% of the time.